# How can define / use a dynamic variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently defining multiple global JS vars in a PHP foreach within a div this way:

```
<script>
    var signaturePad<?= $i ?>;
</script>
```

Output:

```
var signaturePadYWduZFlQVm9xS1dhNDJYYU1ZdCtWUT09;
```

I need to do this because I later need to get some content from the global var depending on the shown div.

Now I've the problem that I don't know how I can use the generated variable in JS. I've tried it this way but this can't work:

```
var targetId = jQuery(this).attr('data-target-id'); //The id after signaturePad....
signaturePad + targetId = new SignaturePad();
```

Later I need to get for example a signature from the object:

```
signaturePad + targetId.toDataURL('image/png')
```

Any idea how I can deal with this?

Comment: Use an object (or array) instead

Comment: Can you give me an example? :) I've never done this before..

Comment: See the linked canonical.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Still not logic to me how I can use this correctly :/

Comment: And the answer returns just a number but concats nothing (in the duplicate)

Comment: Eg `const signaturePad = { YWduZFlQVm9xS1dhNDJYYU1ZdCtWUT09: <value> }` and then use plain bracket notation to assign or look up the value

Comment: You mean: signaturePad = {
    targetId: new SignaturePad(signaturePadCanvas)
}; ???

Comment: No, that would have only a single property, `targetId`, not the (dynamic) property `YWduZFlQVm9xS1dhNDJYYU1ZdCtWUT09` that you're looking for

Comment: But target id is defined dynamically. See above. The target ID is a unique ID of the div where the signature pad is inside.

Comment: Exactly, so you have to use bracket notation to assign or look up the property

Comment: I don't get it anymore 

Comment: @CertainPerformance Can you please give me a short example with my implementation, so that I can understand it?

Comment: Define the pads with `const signaturePad = { YWduZFlQVm9xS1dhNDJYYU1ZdCtWUT09: <value> }`. If there's no initial value, just use an empty object. Then retrieve / assign to properties of the object. eg `signaturePad[foo] = 'bar'`

Comment: In my main js I now did: let signaturePad; in PHP this: <script>
    signaturePad[] = '<?= $id ?>';
</script> but this generates an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

Comment: Since it looks like you're not assigning values to the object initially, leave that out entirely - just create an empty object

Comment: I'll re-write my question above with the new implementation, ok?